# xcode 7 svn checkout subdirectory

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I'm using Xcode 7.2 and about to checkout subdirectory of a svn repository. For example, if a repository path is **svn://mysvn.com/svn/trunk/ios/MyXcodeProject**, I want to checkout **ONLY** **'MyXcodeProject'** via Xcode and keep it under version control.
I don't want to checkout all of the subdirectories that I don't care under 'trunk', like android, web, documents etc..
I tried Xcode menu > Source Control > Checkout... by entering the whole repository path(svn://mysvn.com/svn/trunk/ios/MyXcodeProject), however it checked out all of the directories under trunk although those are under version control.

I remember the earlier version of Xcode provided subdirectory checkout but it seems Xcode 7.x~ does not.
Are there any person suffering this problem? Which is the best way I can choose?

Comment: So. You can checkout your folder via command line `svn co ..` and then to open it from `xcode`. The best way is use `git + Xcode` or `svn + AppCode`. IMHO the `Xcode` is not friendly with `svn`.

Comment: @Mozilla I tried command line checkout but the subdirectory itself is not set to be under version control. In the end, I checked out the whole trunk. It frustrates. Thank you for comment.

Comment: @EddyOh I had the same problem, and I have no solution yet. Did you solve the problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I imported it to to root of the repo, so not under /trunk/myapp but to /myapp.

After that I could checkout the project folder successfully.